# Mysql REGEXP exact same string

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to fetch all those results with same exact string, but the query below is returning results matching all strings having Cars, but I need only results which match exact to Cars

```
SELECT i.name
FROM table_name i
WHERE i.name REGEXP '[[:<:]]Cars[[:>:]]'
```

I thought [[:<:]] [[:>:]] would restrict the result to having **only** exact value

EDIT:

MY bad I didnt mention, the above is just an example, Instead of just cars there will be multiple strings, like

```
SELECT i.name
    FROM table_name i
    WHERE i.name REGEXP '[[:<:]]Cars[[:>:]].[[:<:]]Movies[[:>:]].[[:<:]]Camping[[:>:]]''
```

> There will be multiple strings to match depending on the conditions. I
>   am trying Regexp because else I will have to explicitly declare LIKE
>   without % for all strings.
>
> The Only reason I am using REGEXP is because I can pass my strings at
>   once by concatenating, which is not possible using LIKE as much as I
>   know

```
My table

**ColumnName**
Cars
Racing Cars
Movies
Romantic Movies
```

By using the above query I get all results related to cars and movies, instead I only need the exact match

**Cars & Movies** only

Comment: Why won't `WHERE i.name = 'Cars'` do what you want?

Comment: If I did not miss anything, you want a simple comparison of i.name with the string 'Cars'. In this case, there is no reason to use regular expressions, you can use mySQL string comparison functions (LIKE etc.).

Comment: @HoboSapiens, its just an example, I would be passing multiple values by concatinating

Comment: Then you need to post a better example. I don't see what you're getting at.

Comment: @HoboSapiens please check the edit if you can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Deepanshu, I see that you use REGEXP, perhaps because your implementation limits you in a way that you give as a parameter to a function the whole string that will be used in a REGEXP expression. `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` match the beginning and the end of a certain matching word and not the whole string. So, you want to use `^` and `$` respectively and the exact query you will use is :

```
SELECT i.name
FROM table_name i
WHERE i.name REGEXP '(^Cars$)|(^Movies$)|(^Camping$)'
```

However, since I notice a lot of people keep on using mySQL REGEXP for straight equality comparison, this is not a good practice and I suggest changing your implementation so that it uses `LIKE`,equality or something similar. You could also produced dynamically a LIKE statement using a programming language.

Comment: yes even I feel so REGEXP is not for such simple comparisons, its just I was trying to skip a for loop. Thank you so much for the solution

Comment: I am very bad at regex stuff, could you please tell me if there any good documentation particularly for REGEX only

Comment: Since you are using REGEXP for mySQL, I suggest starting from the following documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html. Also, you can use online debuggers to test your regexp expressions fastly, like https://regex101.com/

Comment: The pattern should be `'^(Cars|Movies|Camping)$'` - shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Why to use Regex when you want the exact match. Simply try this

```
SELECT i.name
FROM table_name i
WHERE i.name = 'CARS'
```

or

```
SELECT i.name
FROM table_name i
WHERE i.name like '%CARS%'
```

Remove the left or right wild character % as per your string and pattern

**EDIT:-**

So as per your edit, if you want to match only Cars and Movies then you can write like this:

```
SELECT i.name
FROM table_name i
WHERE i.name IN ('CARS','MOVIES')
```

Comment: There will be multiple strings to match, I am passing all of them using REGEXP at once by concating them by dot

Comment: @Deepanshu:- Without examples it is hard to understand what you want. But in that case you can try with LIKE as well!

Comment: @Deepanshu:- It would be better if you can post an example for your match. The edit still is not very clear. :(

Comment: Please check the edit now, The Only reason I am using REGEXP is because I can pass multiple strings at once by concatenating, which is not possible using LIKE as much as I know, so that any matching result will be returned